# how to assign the attribute name to a string array for more namespaces

Tags: c#, xml

i have to get name attribute of namespace thredds to a string array.i need to get the name of file to array(thredds:dataset name).
i tried    `doc.Root.Elements ()select dataset` and

```
var 
names = rows.Select(o => (string)o.Element("name")).ToArray();
```

but not working.please suggest me.The xml is like this

```
<thredds:catalog xmlns:thredds="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:bes="http://xml.opendap.org/ns/bes/1.0#">
<thredds:service name="dap" serviceType="OPeNDAP" base="/opendap/hyrax"/>
<thredds:service name="file" serviceType="HTTPServer" base="/opendap/hyrax"/>
<thredds:service name="wms" serviceType="WMS" base="/ncWMS/wms"/>
<thredds:dataset name="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/">
<thredds:dataset name="OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5">
<thredds:dataSize units="bytes">3003100</thredds:dataSize>
<thredds:date type="modified">2014-01-03T06:48:48</thredds:date>
<thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5"/>
<thredds:access serviceName="wms" urlPath="?DATASET=lds/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"/>
</thredds:dataset>
<thredds:dataset name="OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5">
<thredds:dataSize units="bytes">3030178</thredds:dataSize>
<thredds:date type="modified">2014-01-04T05:49:18</thredds:date>
<thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5"/>
<thredds:access serviceName="wms" urlPath="?DATASET=lds/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"/>
</thredds:dataset>
<thredds:dataset name="OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5">
<thredds:dataSize units="bytes">3019723</thredds:dataSize>
<thredds:date type="modified">2014-01-05T06:49:33</thredds:date>
<thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5"/>
<thredds:access serviceName="wms" urlPath="?DATASET=lds/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"/>
</thredds:dataset>
```

Comment: Your attributes do not belong to any namespace. And in your code you are trying to get Elements and not Attributes. I would think something like this should work but have not tested: `rows.Descendants().SelectMany(e=> e.Attribute("name")).Where(a => a != null).ToArray();`

Comment: i tried this but not working